# How do I read a csv file from google drive folder using python, without downloading it

Tags: python, pandas, google-drive-api

I need to read a csv file which is present in google drive folder using python, I do not want to download or change it into a different format, is there any way I could get the csv file url to read the file?

I can see there is no csv file url in google drive

Comment: I don't think Google provides direct downloads for files hosted in Google Drive, as doing so may allow many potential abuses. You have to use a library to do so.

Answer (score 0):

If its a CSV file i would recommend converting it to a google sheets file then you can just update it via the Google sheets api.

You cant write directly to a file on google drive without downloading it first.  I have done something like what you are looking for in C# [How to upload to Google Drive API from memory with C#](https://www.daimto.com/how-to-upload-to-google-drive-api-from-memory-with-c/)  Once you download the file into a memory stream you will have access to it so you could change the text then upload it again.

unfortunately what you want to do isnt exactly possible.  Let me know if you need help converting it to google sheets or translating my C# tutorial into python.  It should be doable in python as well.

## update

Got board and i was curious, you can upload memory stream to Google drive as well.

```
# create drive api client
service = build('drive', 'v3', credentials=creds)
file_metadata = {'name': 'Upload.txt'}
fh = io.StringIO("some initial text data")
media = MediaIoBaseUpload(fh, mimetype='text/plain')

file = service.files().create(body=file_metadata, media_body=media,
                                  fields='id').execute()
print(F'File ID: {file.get("id")}')
```